# How to assess if biological measurements follow a normal or a log-normal distribution

Tags: bioinformatics, statistics, biostatistics

I am using a dataset composed by $m$ samples and $n$ features (genes). Each data point is real number.

I want to understand how to preprocess data before analysis, in particular: do data points follow a normal or a log-normal distribution?

I thought about using qqplots and searching for different tests to assess the form of the distribution, but I have a doubt:

Do I have to assess the form of:

- each sample distribution
- each feature (gene) distribution
- the whole dataset ($m$ samples x $n$ features (genes))

?

Comment: This might be better suited for [stats.se]

Comment: @C_Z_ you are right, but I thought it may be a task well-known for bioinformaticians, e.g. while using microarrays. However, if not, how can I transfer it to CV? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/37167/3340

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From personal experience, nearly all count data whether from microarray or reads from RNAseq of some kind, requires a log transformation of the counts. Usually a small fraction is added to all values before doing so to zero protect. Log2(counts + 0.5) or some such.   This is independent of the treatments. If you log transform one sample, you will do the same for all samples. To examine for normality, a simple way is to look at the histogram of counts (by all samples or by each sample) before and after transformation. Roughly bell shaped -> proceed.

Pictures below from my data. Although the data are from RNAseq, microarray data should be similar.

R code here:

```
hist(t$counts,breaks=100,main="Histogram of Raw Counts from RNAseq")
hist(log(t$counts + 0.5,2),breaks=100,main="Histogram of Log2
transformed Counts from RNAseq")
```

[image]

Comment: There are ways to statistically check for normality, and I find visually examining the data as I listed above is a good first step.

Answer (score 3):

- Preprocessing will and should always depend upon the biology that you try to answer or discover (e.g.: There might be an experimental rationale to believe that some genes behave differently in individual samples - and that different samples could possibly have different distributions.)
- log-transforming your data by itself is usually no problem, and hugely facilitates the simultaneous exploration of different magnitudes (though adding a small value prior log can soon make your analysis misleading, if you intended to quantitatively study variance across samples)
- For testing normality you might want to apply the [Lilliefors test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliefors_test) on raw data and log-transformed data
- If you are using a readout of gene-expression you must not anticipate a unimodal distribution, e.g.: Metazoans have two different classes of genes, which overall lead to a bi-modal distribution ([Hebenstreit et al. 2011](http://msb.embopress.org/content/7/1/497.long)) (If you can fit any unimodal  distribution - such as lognormal - you should become very suspicious and check the quality of the experimental data.)